# Как заблокировать свайп при свайпе по определённому блоку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullpage

Здрасте. У меня в проекте есть поблочная прокрутка (использую библиотеку [fullPage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)). И есть блок, при свайпе по которому выводиться alert. Но при свайпе по блоку, так же листается и страница. так вот задача: как при свайпе по блоку, заблокировать прокрутку страницы. Если это не возможно с этой библиотекой, посоветуйте другую или реализацию на JavaScript (jQuery). А так же С Новым Годом!

Answer (score 0):

Очень сложно полностью понять вопрос без примера кода.
Попробуйте дополнить вопрос кодом как в ответе ниже и
тогда будет возможность скорректировать ответ.

А пока возможно Вам будет достаточно примера из "книжки"
Обратите внимание на нижеследующие функции:

[**`onLeave (index, nextIndex, direction)`**](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/lang/russian#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) - Этот обратный вызов активируется, когда пользователь покидает раздел, при переходе к новому разделу. Возврат `false` отменит переход до его осуществления. Можно так же использовать `moveSectionUp()` или `moveSectionDown()` для возврата к предыдущему слайду, это тоже может быть эффектным.

[**`setAllowScrolling(логическая операция, [направления])`**](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/lang/russian#setallowscrolling%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) - Даёт или убирает возможность скроллинга разделов/слайдов с помощью колеса мыши/трекпада или сенсорных жестов(включено по умолчанию). Обратите внимание, что функция не деактивирует скроллинг с помощью клавиатуры. Для этого вам потребуется использовать `setKeyboardScrolling`.

Отключение прокрутки, например для `body {overflow: hidden;}`.

Надеюсь этой информации будет достаточно чтоб Ваш код был исправлен таким образом, что приведёт к требуему результату.

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx',
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
});

//adding the actions to the buttons
document.getElementById('turnOff').addEventListener('click', function(){
  fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false);
  fullpage_api.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
 
  
});

document.getElementById('turnOn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
  fullpage_api.setKeyboardScrolling(true);
  
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
}


/**
Fixed button outside the fullpage.js wrapper
*/
#turnOff,
#turnOn{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor:pointer;
  top: 20px;
}
#turnOff{
  left: 20px;
}
#turnOn{
  left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.css" integrity="sha512-1No3nMY/zD37h1POyqULfwc9WMzWvXcal6F7/OIhNdWkTaEbt4Y6eqX0vXail7Zh5JjnBdMMKr+lRvqTNFr3Ow==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.js" integrity="sha512-eH2N2Zt2AeLuFlFvRSEeZcVeAESY+8nfIqhxx0XXEou6w/G4lLY3K8UKNYqi6e1pLXDduVF1KF/lbyxy3+X6OA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button id="turnOff">Not allow</button>
<button id="turnOn">Allow</button>


<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```